# How are signals handled in main thread sent by other thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, signals

The code is from [PyMOTW signal chapter](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/signal/index.html#signals-and-threads). Why is the alarm signal not handled immediately by the main thread when it is signaled by the alarm_thread. The output from the author show the alarm signal is handled when the alarm thread finishes(`alarm_thread.join()` returns).

```
import signal
import time
import threading

def signal_handler(num, stack):
    print time.ctime(), 'Alarm in', threading.currentThread()

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)

def use_alarm():
    print time.ctime(), 'Setting alarm in', threading.currentThread()
    signal.alarm(1)
    print time.ctime(), 'Sleeping in', threading.currentThread()
    time.sleep(3)
    print time.ctime(), 'Done with sleep'

# Start a thread that will not receive the signal
alarm_thread = threading.Thread(target=use_alarm, name='alarm_thread')
alarm_thread.start()
time.sleep(0.1)

# Wait for the thread to see the signal (not going to happen!)
print time.ctime(), 'Waiting for', alarm_thread
alarm_thread.join()

print time.ctime(), 'Exiting normally'
```

output by the author:

```
$ python signal_threads_alarm.py
Sun Aug 17 12:06:00 2008 Setting alarm in <Thread(alarm_thread, started)>
Sun Aug 17 12:06:00 2008 Sleeping in <Thread(alarm_thread, started)>
Sun Aug 17 12:06:00 2008 Waiting for <Thread(alarm_thread, started)>;
Sun Aug 17 12:06:03 2008 Done with sleep
Sun Aug 17 12:06:03 2008 Alarm in <_MainThread(MainThread, started)>
Sun Aug 17 12:06:03 2008 Exiting normally
```

In my opinion, the output should like below. Alarm signal should handled by the main thread `before` alarm thread sleep finishes, and `alarm_thread.join()` returns.

```
$ python signal_threads_alarm.py
Sun Aug 17 12:06:00 2008 Setting alarm in <Thread(alarm_thread, started)>
Sun Aug 17 12:06:00 2008 Sleeping in <Thread(alarm_thread, started)>
Sun Aug 17 12:06:00 2008 Waiting for <Thread(alarm_thread, started)>;
Sun Aug 17 12:06:03 2008 Alarm in <_MainThread(MainThread, started)>
Sun Aug 17 12:06:03 2008 Done with sleep
Sun Aug 17 12:06:03 2008 Exiting normally
```